# Base class is unitialized while being accessed

Tags: c++, class, initialization

The following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int a;
    virtual int foo(){ std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl; return 5; }
    A(int a) : a(a){ }
};

struct B : A{
    B() : A(foo()){ }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/509f9de933968795)

produces a warning about

```
warning: base class 'A' is uninitialized when used here to access 'A::foo'
```

Does it mean that the accessing to the base class while it's not initialized yields `Undefined Behavior`?

In my case, `A::a` got the value `5` and it's ok.

Comment: If `foo` accesses any member variables of `A` (which might not exist now but might exist later) then you can get undefined behavior. If `foo` becomes a virtual function, or calls a virtual function, you can get very surprising results.

Comment: what happens when we make 'a' a static variable for A::a?

Comment: @vishal The program will no longer compile, as a static member cannot be listed in constructor initializer list.

Comment: thanks for knowledge :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's undefined behavior (IIRC) because `foo` is a virtual method.

If `foo` wasn't virtual the behavior would be defined, but it would nevertheless be a questionable idea to call the method before the object has been initialized.